# How to set maximum length in String value DART

Tags: string, dart

i am trying to set maximum length in string value and put '..' instead of removed chrs like following

`String myValue =` 'Welcome'

now i need the maximum length is 4 so output like following

```
'welc..'
```

how can i handle this ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The short and incorrect version is:

```dart
String abbrevBad(String input, int maxlength) {
  if (input.length <= maxLength) return input;
  return input.substring(0, maxLength - 2) + "..";
}
```

(Using `..` is not the typographical way to mark an elision. That takes `...`, the "ellipsis" symbol.)

A more internationally aware version would count grapheme clusters instead of code units, so it handles complex characters and emojis as a single character, and doesn't break in the middle of one. Might also use the proper [ellipsis character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2026).

```dart
String abbreviate(String input, int maxLength) {
  var it = input.characters.iterator;
  for (var i = 0; i <= maxLength; i++) {
    if (!it.expandNext()) return input;
  }
  it.dropLast(2);
  return "${it.current}\u2026";
}
```

That also works for characters which are not single code units:

```dart
void main() {
  print(abbreviate("argelbargle", 7)); // argelb…
  print(abbreviate("", 4)); // …
}
```

(If you want to use `...` instead of `…`, just change `.dropLast(2)` to `.dropLast(4)` and `"…"` to `"..."`.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `RichText` and you need to specify the overflow type, just like this:

```dart
Flexible(
  child: RichText("Very, very, very looong text", 
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  ),
);
```

If the `Text` widget overflows, some points (`...`) will appears.